# Proving that $X_t = W_t~ I (0<t\le T) + (2W_T - W_t) ~I(t > T)$ is a brownian motoin

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The steps to showing that a process is a BM are as follows:

(1)$X_0 = 0$

(2) $ \forall t ~~~X_t$ is continuous

(3)$X_t \sim N(0,t)$

(4)$X_{t+s}-X_{s} \sim N(0,t)$

(5)$X_{t+s}-X_{s} \bot \mathscr F_s=(W_u)_{u\in(0,s)} $

If $W_t$ is a Standard Brownian Motion. $X_t = W_t~  I (0<t\le T) + (2W_T - W_t) ~I(t > T)$, where I is the indicator function taking the value of 1 if t is in the specified range.

I am having trouble showing step (3)

my attempt is to just break this up into cases:

Case 1: $t<T \implies X_t=W_t$ which is clearly normal with mean zero and variance t

Case 2: $t>T \implies X_t = 2W_T - W_t$. Here, $W_T$ is a constant as we are in the period of time after T has occured. So wouldn't this process not have a zero mean? but i know that $X_t$  is in fact a brownian motion.

for this process though, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think that is does not have zero mean? Note that $$\mathbb{E}(X_t) = 2 \mathbb{E}(W_T)- \mathbb{E}(W_t) = 2 \cdot 0 - 0 = 0$$ for any $t>T$.

Comment: @saz this is what i'm confused about, if we are in the time t>T then W(T) has already been observed, and so its expectation is equal to just what it is right? Whereas you're saying that its expectation is 0 as if we are looking at it from time zero. Why is that the correct view point

Comment: @dimebucker91, what is the definition of $T$: is it a constant or some random variable?

Comment: @ki3i its not defined in the question but i suspect it means the stopping time. I know that the stopping time is a rv, but if we are finding the distribution of Xt at time t>T even if T was a rv it has been observed now, thats my confusion

Comment: @dimebucker91 $W_T$ is simply a random variable with mean $0$. There is no "we are looking from time zero" or "we are looking from the future". It is what it is: A random variable. If you know the value of a random variable, say $X(\omega)$, then this doesn't change anything about the expectation of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,{\{\mathcal F_t\}}_{t\geqslant 0},\mathbb P)$ be the underlying filtered probability space and let $T$ be a stopping time. Consider the following processes:

1. $W_t~$ for $0<t\leqslant T$;
2. $W_{t}-W_T~$ for $T< t$;
3. $-(W_{t}-W_T)~$ for $T< t$.

By the [strong Markov property of Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Strong_Markov_property), processes $(2)$ and $(3)$ are Brownian motions, each independent of process $(1)$. Furthermore, adding process $(2)$ to $(1)$ gives Brownian motion $W_t$, while adding process $(3)$ to $(1)$ gives $X_t$. Since $(2)$ and $(3)$ are identically distributed processes, then $X_t$ is Brownian motion.